# Automatic mount in zfsonlinux on Debian jessie

Tags: linux, debian, mount, zfs

I just upgraded from Debian wheezy (and the old zfsonlinux packages) to Debian jessie (and the new jessie-backports packages). Now on system start, the ZFS pools are neither imported nor mounted. I can import and mount my pools manually with

```
zpool import zpool1
zfs mount -a
```

How is this supposed to work with the new system? What are the packages to be installed? `/etc/init.d/zfs` does not even exist any more on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been hit by this issue and I think I might know why you're affected by it too.

The new ZFS packages in Debian don't have LSB init scripts any more, which is why you don't see anything in the `/etc/init.d/` directory.

They only provide systemd unit files. You can see the file lists here (assuming you're using the amd64 architecture). https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/zfsutils-linux/filelist

My machine had also been upgraded to Debian Jessie and I found out that I was still using `sysvinit` as the init system, whereas a new install gets `systemd` by default.

I confirmed this by running `cat /proc/1/comm` and the output was: `init`

I then switched to systemd by running `apt-get install systemd-sysv`

This removed the conflicting `sysvinit-core` package.

Please refer to the Debian wiki page for systemd and don't blame me if it breaks your system. https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Configuring_as_default

There will be other ways to create LSB compliant boot scripts, if you don't want to change your init system. I haven't investigated them yet.

Comment: Thank you; that's super disappointing. A simple update and everything breaks. Any ideas how to get the sysv scripts? I can't use systemd ...

Comment: Here is the relevant Debian bug:

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826994 - It looks like you can copy the LSB init scripts from the previous version, but they're not *fully* compatible, in that they may generate warnings. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Is this been fix ? Or that's still an issue ?